# how to make responsive a div holding 2 divs in the right and left with image depending on screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css

supposing I have a div that holds 2 divs,

Is there a way to make it responsive depending on screen size?
I want to apply this to a mobile version but I am getting all messed up...

```
<div id="primary">
<div id="left"><div id="object1" align='justify'>
<br/><br/>
<p>
If you told me this was a computer generated image of a mothership hovering over a planet's surface, I would have believed you. Instead, I had to look up desmids, which turned out to be a form of green algae. I would have guessed this is a cell in the process of dividing, but it turns out that one of the characteristic features of desmids is that they're a single cell divided into two compartments. (See, even I'm learning something from this.) Desmids are so tiny that this image was taken at 100x power. The green backdrop? It's a moss.
</p>
</div></div>

<div id="right"><div id="object3">
<b><h2>title</h2></b>
<img class="align-right" alt="" src="http://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/09_Place_22047_3_Drange.jpg"  style="width:200px" /></div></div></div>
```

The image and div I do not know how to reduce it depending on screen size...

please teake a look [at a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FgnpL/)
In fact I cannot make the div to hold 2 columns the image is under and not at the same level of left column...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have percentage padding and margin also, just apply some maths...

***LeftDiv(padding:1% + margin:1% + width:44%) + RightDiv(padding:1% + margin:1% + width:44%) = 100%***

Padding and margin is for top,bottom,left, right 1%,1%,1%,1%...

**CSS:-**

```
#left, #right {
    margin: 1%;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 43%;
}
```

If you want the image to be responsive too make its `width:100%;`

http://jsfiddle.net/FgnpL/5/

Comment: Is there a way to apply that to `p` also as the image ?